# Custom object binding for JSON requests using Volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm studying Volley library and in particular I'm dealing with `JSONObject` requests. In several tutorials I can find examples like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
    url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    , new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

but now I'm wondering if there is a way to bind a custom class to request object or result object.

I mean: I'd like to map the key-value result to some strong-typed custom object in my app domain. Is this possible or should I implement this feature by myself?

Comment: You can use `Gson` to unmarshal the `JSONObject` into your custom object. But out of curiosity, why not just `Retrofit`?

Comment: @W.K.S I'm new to Android and I'm evaluating some libraries. I didn't know about Retrofit lib. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Oh, if you're new to Android, go for Retrofit and never look back. It really saves time and code + unlike Volley, it has much better documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would help you.

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,url,your_json_object,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                       // On Success
                     }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       // On Failure                           
                    }
                });
 MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest, tag);
```

Pass your `your_json_object` instead of mine.

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library like this:
https://gist.github.com/ficusk/5474673

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your goal is to GET a Name object, where Name is defined as

```
public class Name{
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;

    //constructor, getter, setter
}
```

then you could use Gson to convert the JSONObject to Name

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
    url, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Name name = gson.fromJson(response.toString(),Name.class);

            //use Name.
        }
    }
    , new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

@Lissf's answer is a good way to avoid boilerplate.

However, I would recommend checking out [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) which can reduce this down to a single line:

```
@GET ("/name")
getName(Callback<Name> nameCallback);
```

You might want to check out [RxAndroid](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/) as well.